# Why a bitwise not followed by a right shift pads with ones instead of zeros only for some integral types?

Tags: c++

I was working on a bitset class (yes I know of std::bitset) when I noticed that some tests failed only for a few unsigned integral types. Then I discovered that a bitwise not followed by a right shift (to generate a mask) pads the result with ones instead of zeros as for int and other larger integral types.

For example:

```cpp
    uint8_t result = (~(uint8_t(0))) >> 2;
```

will produce 0xFF instead of 0x3F.

I wrote the following test

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
std::string hex( const T& );

template<typename T>
void test(const std::string& name)
{
    T value1 = (~T(0)) >> 2;
    T ones = ~T(0);
    T value2 = ones >> 2;
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << name << "  "
              << std::setw(16) << hex(value1) << " "
              << std::setw(16) << hex(value2) << "   "
              << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
}

#define TEST(x) test<x>(#x)

int main()
{
    TEST(bool);
    TEST(char);
    TEST(unsigned char);
    TEST(std::int8_t);
    TEST(std::uint8_t);
    TEST(short);
    TEST(unsigned short);
    TEST(char16_t);
    TEST(wchar_t);
    TEST(std::int16_t);
    TEST(std::uint16_t);
    TEST(int);
    TEST(unsigned int);
    TEST(std::int32_t);
    TEST(std::uint32_t);
    TEST(long);
    TEST(unsigned long);
    TEST(std::int64_t);
    TEST(std::uint64_t);
    TEST(std::intptr_t);
    TEST(std::size_t);
    TEST(long long);
    TEST(unsigned long long);
    TEST(std::byte);
    TEST(char8_t);
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
                bool                01               00 b
                char                ff               ff c
       unsigned char                ff               3f h
              int8_t                ff               ff a
             uint8_t                ff               3f h
               short              ffff             ffff s
      unsigned short              ffff             3fff t
            char16_t              ffff             3fff Ds
             wchar_t          ffffffff         ffffffff w
             int16_t              ffff             ffff s
            uint16_t              ffff             3fff t
                 int          ffffffff         ffffffff i
        unsigned int          3fffffff         3fffffff j
             int32_t          ffffffff         ffffffff i
            uint32_t          3fffffff         3fffffff j
                long  ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff l
       unsigned long  3fffffffffffffff 3fffffffffffffff m
             int64_t  ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff l
            uint64_t  3fffffffffffffff 3fffffffffffffff m
       std::intptr_t  ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff l
         std::size_t  3fffffffffffffff 3fffffffffffffff m
           long long  ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff x
  unsigned long long  3fffffffffffffff 3fffffffffffffff y
           std::byte                3f               3f St4byte
             char8_t                ff               3f Du
```

The result is consistent across compilers and versions since gcc 4.8.5 at least.

Full test on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/8YWWqxW5K

The question is: is there any standards clause to support this behavior?

Or it's just undefined behavior and consensus by chance?

Comment: You need to narrow to `T` before shifting: `T value1 = T(~T{0}) >> numbits;`.

Comment: Your code was incomplete and wouldn't compile.  I wasn't expecting you to change it whilst I was repairing it.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher A Godbolt link is not enough on StackOverflow. Quote from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so—but **also copy the code into the question itself.**"_

Comment: What's wrong with adding the full code to the question? It's indeed customary here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for your confusion is that the binary not (`~` tilde) operator will promote the operand to `int32` prior to the operation and the shift `>>` operator will be applied to an integer of type `int32`.

As the shift operand is negative, it will be appended with ones to the left, contrary to your original intention of shifting right to fill up with zeros.

To deal with a real example, let's analyze what happens in this expression:

```cpp
uint16_t value = (~uint16_t(0)) >> 8
```

From a first glance many people would expect the result to be `0xff` because `~0 = 0xffff` then `0xffff >> 8 = 0xff`.

However that's not what happens. The sequence of operations are:

```cpp
0. input = u16(0)
1. i32(u16(0)) = i32(0)
2. ~i32(0) = i32(0xffffffff)
3. i32(0xffffffff) >> 8 = i32(0xffffffff) by ***sign extension***
4. u16(i32(0xffffffff)) = u16(0xffff)
5. result = u16(0xffff) when the expected was u16(0xff)
```

Therefore shifting right as a means to fill up a number of zero bits to the left does not work as intended when applied naively to unsigned small integers u8 and u16 (assuming int = i32).

Therefore a good practice in these cases is to cast the integer back to the original small type before shifting as in

```cpp
uint16_t value = uint16_t(~uint16_t(0)) >> 8;
```

This will produce the expected value of 0xff.

Answer (score 2):

All bitwise operations promote their small-typed arguments to `int`.

`~(uint8_t(0))` - the arg is promoted to `int` and the result is `0xffffffff`.

`uint8_t result = ~(uint8_t(0))>>2;` is `uint8_t result = 0xffffffff>>2;`, and `result` is `0xffU`.

Some cases have undefined behavior: `(uint32_t)((~uint16_t(0))>>28)`

[Shift operators](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift#1)

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and **integral promotions are performed**. The type of the result is that of **the promoted left operand**. **The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative**, or greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

Comment: This is the standard, inherits C integer promotion.

Comment: [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) has the overloaded `operator~` and `operator>>`

Comment: @HenriqueBucher It's not padding. In `~uint16_t(0)` it toggles the bits of an `int`.

Comment: So if it is just about the shift operator, why does `uint8_t result = (uint8_t(255)) >> 2;` give `63`? It seems `~` is responsible for the promotion. `uint8_t result = uint8_t(~((uint8_t)0)) >> 2;` gives `63`.

`

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Make the `int` `unsigned` and you'd get `0xF`. What you're getting now is called sign extension

Comment: `uint8_t(255)` is 0xFF -> promotes to 0x000000FF int -> 0x0000003F after shifting -> 63,

Comment: @HenriqueBucher What do you mean by _"it does not_"? `~0u >> 28` results in `0xF` when `unsigned` is a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: I don't get your comments. You talk "gives 63" two times. And "it's what should happen" in the last comment. I don't understand.

Comment: @SomethingSomething You are missing the point. You are back to `int` with that example, not an `unsigned int`, this `~uint8_t(0)`  is a `signed int` - and when you right shift it, you're getting _sign extension_.

Comment: @SomethingSomething It's padded with 0's to form an `int` before `~` is applied.

Comment: @SomethingSomething 1. In `~uint8_t(0)` the `uint8_t` is first padded with 0's to form an `int`. 2. `~` then toggles the bits and you now have an `int` with the sign-bit set. 3. When you right-shift, that sign-bit is copied in as many times as you right-shift. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/df5Kv5o7j)